# Is there jerk on Uniform Circular Motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, centripetal-force, jerk

I was reading my textbook and I encountered a section where it explains that Centripetal Acceleration is not constant, thus, I wonder if [jerk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_%28physics%29) exists in Uniform Circular Motion? The textbook states that it happens due to the continuous change on the vector's direction. So, pretty much. Does jerk manifest? or, if it does not, why?

Comment: What do you mean by jerk "manifesting"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Jerk and Snap in Circular Motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/303957/jerk-and-snap-in-circular-motion)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As other answers and comments said, yes there is jerk. But it doesn't mean what you think. In everyday use, a jerk is a sudden acceleration, like a sudden yank on a rope. That is not what centripetal acceleration is like.

If you tie a rope to a rock and swing it around your head, you must pull on the rope to keep it moving in a circle. That is centripetal force and centripetal acceleration. If the rock is circling at a constant radius and speed, the magnitude of the force does not change. The direction smoothly changes. You have to keep pulling toward yourself as the rock moves around you.

The other answers about jerk, snap, crackle, and pop are apparently technical terms for higher derivatives of velocity. Though I had never heard of them before this question. They are not in common use. And these technical definitions do not imply sudden accelerations either.

Jerk is the derivative of acceleration. It is a semi-good name. It makes more sense to apply it to the derivative of force than acceleration.

Suppose you are pulling with constant force on a rope, trying to move a stuck object. You give the rope a yank. The force momentarily rises and then returns to its former value. The derivative of force reasonably fits the idea of jerking the rope, even if the object is still stuck. If the object breaks free and there is a non-zero acceleration, then the derivative of acceleration also reasonably fits the idea.

Jerk is a non-zero vector in uniform circular motion. But the motion does not fit the everyday idea of jerking the rope.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114028/discussion-on-answer-by-mmesser314-is-there-jerk-on-uniform-circular-motion).

Comment: G.Smith: yes it is entirely necessary to emphasize, when some. Many readers of Physics.SE will be HS grads or laymen, and as I illustrate when even 2nd-year Eng students find this issue counterintuitive, it's counterintuitive. @Fattie's comment *"There is utterly no distinction between "technical" and "non-technical" uses, whatever that means"* is factually incorrect, and a seriously damaging attitude to actually educating site users and correcting misunderstandings in learning.

Comment: Other than the absolutely common, totally settled physics usage, the word "jerk" in daily English in non-physics means "tug" - it is utterly evident the OP is discussing the physics usage of "jerk" (note that the OP even *gives a link* for goodness sake). Note too that the sentence "Jerk is a non-zero vector in uniform circular motion." is completely, totally, absolutely wrong.  The sentence "They are not in common use" is totally incorrect.   The passages explaining what jerk "should" mean (??) and that the writer has never heard the term before are just bizarre.  Delete.

Answer (score 17):

Jerk is the change in acceleration.  If acceleration is changing, then there is jerk.  Since there is a changing acceleration in circular motion, there is jerk in circular motion.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "manifest" though.  It's simply something that can be measured.

Comment: I think he's using "manifest" to mean "to be present in this situation". I felt it was proper usage and didn't think twice about it.

Comment: To clarify slightly: the *magnitude* of the acceleration is constant but its direction is constantly changing; therefore there is jerk.  Likewise the direction of the jerk is constantly changing, the direction of snap (derivative of jerk) is constantly changing ... it's circular all the way down.

Comment: The use of manifest is, IMO, *slightly incorrect*.  When you are asking "is X there, or not" (perhaps gravity, electric charge, happiness) you don't, really, ask if it "manifests" which *tends* to mean "becomes apparent".  So, you might say "the disease only manifests itself ..." (in winter, under dyes, whatever).  If you're plain asking "is John Smith in the room or not" "does this cloud have electric charge or not" "is this ball experiencing jerk or not" you're not really asking if it "manifests", the answer is simply yes or no, it's there or not.

Answer (score 0):

Others have explained it well, but I wanted to add another point.

When I think of "jerk", I think of amusement park rides that "jerk" my head around.  With constant acceleration (zero jerk), it's easy to keep your head steady with a constant application of your neck muscles.  When acceleration changes quickly (non-zero jerk), it's hard to keep your head from moving relative to your body.

When I first read your question I thought "It's easy to keep your head steady on a carnival ride shown below, so there must be zero jerk".  **In this case, I think your body has zero jerk in the rotating reference frame centered at the ride's axis.**  In other words, since your body is rotating along with the reference frame, you don't feel the jerk.

[image]

Comment: you are correct. In the non-inertial rotating reference frame, the centrifugal force is constant in both magnitude and direction, and thus there is no jerk.  Your answer most likely got downvoted because it is as much a question as an answer

Comment: @thegreatemu: Thanks for the tip.  I removed the question part of my answer.

Comment: Now that I think about it, this particular ride *does* have jerk when the ride is tilted, because the centrifugal force is aligned/anti-aligned with gravity as the ride spins.  Flat spinning rides have no jerk

Comment: @thegreatemu: +1 Good catch.

Comment: Literally every single use of "acceleration" and "jerk" in this answer is incorrect - surprising on a physics site

Comment: @Fattie: Thanks for your reply.  I acknowledged that my answer only works if we assume that the carnival ride axis is perpendicular to the ground.  What else do you take issue with?  Do you think the riders feel jerk (non-constant acceleration)?

Comment: "jerk" is a completely commonplace term in physics.  (Note there's literally a link in the question.)  You seem to be talking about the "everyday language" use of "jerk" as in "tug" or "pull".  The question is simply and literally about the scientific physics term.

Comment: @Fattie: I know exactly what the physics term means.  In the 2nd paragraph I was trying to relate the common usage of the word "jerk" to the physical meaning.  I think the last 2 sentences of the 2nd paragraph should make that clear.

Comment: Park ride is great analogy. However point, which you move around the circle, does not have direction and your body has. Your analogy would be correct when you would be on that kind of ride, where you are still facing same direction. That way it will not be easy to keep your head still - normal force vector will be rotating relative to your head.